# Oppo find 7: bootloader re-lock impossible?

Tags: fastboot, bootloader-lock, oppo-find-7

I tried to relock the bootloader on my Find 7 (which I'm pretty sure was unlocked since I installed a custom rom).

```
fastboot oem lock
...
```

After that nothing. Windows console is "stuck".
Any clue?

Comment: Just to gauge what you've done, is your device discoverable via `adb` while its on? If so, then run `adb reboot bootloader`, which _should_ then boot to `fastboot` mode. Alternatively it might appear as a selectable option using hw keys. Once in fastboot mode, run `fastboot devices` to see if its recognized.

Comment: fastboot works. and fastboot devices shows my device

Answer (score 0):

I see the same behavior on my Find 7.  I also seem to recall the device *arriving* unlocked.  As far as I can tell, it simply does not support locking the bootloader.

Running `unlock` just instantly says `OK` despite the fact that Developer Options does not contain the "Enable OEM Lock" setting at all (on the latest ColorOS 2.1.5i software, which is Android 5.0 — the version where that feature was added).  I also cannot find anything about (un)locking the Find 7's bootloader online other than one obscure Thai site that seems like it is probably trying to get clicks by reposting the same instructions for multiple devices.